# Why $A\subseteq X$ is dense in $\bar{A}$?

Tags: general-topology

I have a came across the following claim and proof:

claim: let $X$ be a topologic space, $A\subseteq X$, then $A$ is dense in $\bar{A}$

proof: Using the claim that for $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$ the $A$ is dense in $B \Leftrightarrow B \subseteq \bar{A}$ if we take $B$ to be the closure of $A$ then of course that $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{A}$ and $A$ is dense in $A$

So what we can conclude from this claim is that for any set, the set is dense in its closure? in our example $A$ is dense in $\bar{A}$

Comment: for all $A\subset X$, $\bar A$ is dense in $A$, and this is more or less by definition of $\bar A$.

Comment: Isn’t that the definition of $\bar A$?

Comment: What is your definition of "dense"?

Comment: And what is your definition of closure?

Comment: A set $A$ is dense in $X$ if the closure of $A$ is equal to $X$